# Apache directory listing theme

Tags: apache-httpd, apache-virtualhost

How can I set webdav directory listing theme for all shares? Something like [this](https://github.com/ramlmn/Apache-Directory-Listing). But rather in global configuration not separately for every share with `.htaccess` file in every shared folder.

Answer (score 0):

Place the directives in server configuration (`httpd.conf` or better in `httpd.conf.d/` depending on your distribution) to apply them at [global scope](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/configuring.html#scope). Documentation for [*mod_autoindex*](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_autoindex.html) lists all directives to be allowed in *server config* context.

You probably should configure a global alias for the autoindex files so all your *VirtualHosts* can access them using relative paths. See question ["Global Apache Alias, ignoring virtual hosts"](https://serverfault.com/questions/744220/global-apache-alias-ignoring-virtual-hosts/744252#744252) for details.